# Get properties from dynamic object using startswith

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I want to get all properties from json that StartsWith particular text

```
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

So now below is what i get in results

```
{"abc" : "Text", "abcde" : "Text2","prop" : "myprop"}
```

Is it possible to do something like

```
results.Where(x => x.StartsWith("abc"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `results.GetType().GetProperties()`, which will give you an array of properties present in the deserialized JSON object.

You could then iterate over that array to get the `PropertyInfo` objects whose `Name` starts with whatever string you want, and call `GetValue()` to obtain the properties' values of interest.

Or you simply don't deserialize at all, but parse the object and treat it as JSON:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

foreach (var rootProperty in jObject)
{
    if (rootProperty.Key.StartsWith("whatever"))
    {
        var valueOfInterest = rootProperty.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply retrieve the runtime-type of the `result`-object and query its properties using [`Type.GetProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ibrary/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var type = results.GetType();
type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("abc"));
```

EDIT: Because any method called on an instance of `dynamic` is `dynamic` as well, you have to cast the result of `results.GetType` into `Type`. Otherwise you´ll get a compiler-err stating that you can´t use an anonymous method on a dynamically bound operation.

```
var type = (Type)results.GetType();
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it does let me use lambda expression on dynamic type

Comment: Thanks @HimBromBeere. But i used CodeCaster solution.